# an issue about Admob

Tags: android

I just want to ask that is `setGoneWithoutAd()` function available in Android. I tried to use it but it showed:

```
The method setGoneWithoutAd(Boolean) is undefined for the Type AdView
```

Please help if you had experienced it before.